# I need two simultaneous events to happen when user clicks link

Tags: jquery, events, slideshow, simultaneous

When a use clicks on the slideshow's thumbnail (which could be some way down the page) I want the main slideshow image to change AND for the page to scroll to the top (where the actual main image slideshow is happening).

Below are the two script that I have working individually - however I need them to both work simultaneously. I hope someone can help.

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
     $(function() {
$('a.thumnbnail').bind('click',function(event){
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.slideShow').slideShow({
interval: 10
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean you need to have them work simultaneously?

Comment: The above code tells me that when someone clicks on anchor tags with the class "thumbnail" the animation should occur and that when the DOM tree is available for manipulation anything with the class "slideshow" should be attached to the slideShow plugin with an interval of 10 (I assume) seconds.

Comment: Could you provide some information about the slideShow plugin that you're using? It may include some sort of "next" or "prev" type method that would allow you to change its contents through a function call...

Answer (score 0):

No need to call in two different `doc ready`:

```
$(function() {  //<---All in this is enough
    $('a.thumnbnail').bind('click',function(event){
       var $anchor = $(this);
       $('html, body').stop().animate({
           scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
       }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
       event.preventDefault();
    },function(){         // <---------------make this in callback function here
       $('.slideShow').show().slideShow({ // <----display:none initially then show here
        interval: 10
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm using this slideshow: https://github.com/Ephigenia/jquery.slideShow. I want the thumbnail to change the slideshow image and for the page to scroll to top at same time (on the same click).

Comment: Taken 1 step further - would it be possible to have the slideshow hidden until someone clicks a thumbnail and to then have the page scroll to the top where the slideshow div reveals itself and is displaying the large version of the thumbnail that was just clicked. Here's an example of something pretty close: http://kallegustafsson.com/portfolio/

Comment: try using slideshow in callback function, updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean try using in callback function. Do I need to change the code you wrote above somehow?